# Slice a broadcast object?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, masking

I have a 2-dimensional array that represents a mask of a 3-dimensional array, and can be broadcast as such.  e.g.:

```
>>> mask.shape
(101, 100)
>>> cube.shape
(500, 101, 100)
```

What is the best way to create a broadcastable object like `mask` (which is an array) that can be indexed with the same views as cube, returning the same mask?  i.e.:

```
>>> cube[100,:,:]
<some image>
>>> mask[100,:,:]
<mask>
```

so `mask[n,:,:]` would return `mask` for any `n`, or better yet any `n` that could be used to index `cube`.

Importantly, I want to do this *without* making `mask` larger in memory (e.g., by doing `bigger_mask = np.ones([500,1,1])*self._mask[None,:,:]`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
>>> from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import as_strided
>>> mask = np.random.randint(2, size=(101, 100)).astype(bool)
>>> mask_view  = as_strided(mask, shape=(500,)+mask.shape,
...                         strides=(0,)+mask.strides)
>>> mask_view.shape
(500, 101, 100)
>>> np.array_equal(mask_view[0], mask_view[499])
True
>>> np.all(mask_view == 0)
False
>>> mask[:] = 0
>>> np.all(mask_view == 0)
True
```

Comment: This looks great, but it seems that it is still replicating `mask` 500 times in memory: ```>>> mask_view.nbytes
5050000
>>> mask.nbytes
10100```.  Am I misinterpreting what `nbytes` returns?

Comment: [This](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/4cbced22a8306d7214a4e18d12e651c034143922/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarrayobject.h#L82) is the definition in the C source code of how `.size` and `.nbytes` are calculated. It only looks at the shape, but not at the strides, so it does not necessarily represent the actual memory used up. You can check that no extra memory is used by making the first dimension larger that what your RAM would accomodate.

Answer (score 2):

`lib.stride_tricks` makes `broadcast_arrays` available at the `np` level.  It uses `as_strided` as in Jamie's answer, but does not require knowledge of striding.

```
mask1,cube1 =np.broadcast_arrays(mask, cube)
mask1.shape
# (500, 101, 100)
mask1[100,:,:].shape
# (101, 100)
```

`mask1` shares data with `mask`:

```
In [13]: mask1.__array_interface__
Out[13]: 
{'data': (169145016, False),
 'descr': [('', '<f8')],
 'shape': (500, 101, 100),
 'strides': (0, 800, 8),
 'typestr': '<f8',
 'version': 3}
In [14]: mask.__array_interface__
Out[14]: 
{'data': (169145016, False),
 'descr': [('', '<f8')],
 'shape': (101, 100),
 'strides': None,
 'typestr': '<f8',
 'version': 3}
```

Comment: This is good, but it requires me to have the whole `cube` in memory

Comment: It's a view, not a copy.

Comment: But the `cube` object has to exist.  I suppose if it's a `memmap`'d array, it doesn't have to be in memory, but it still has to exist.